# What is the best way to schedule one-time task on Spring boot from a REST endpoint call?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, scheduling

I'm trying to schedule task on Spring boot that executes based on some time duration. Currently I just put the thread in sleep for specified amount of time. This oviously fails for long durations. So, my question is what is the best way to schedule one time task from an endpoint?

P.S : I'm using spring-boot with Mongo as database.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks.

The schedulers can be configured simply and precisely using [Cron Expressions](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks#schedule-a-task-using-cron-expressions).